# Internal server error from controller that has a constructor method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to ASP.NET and C#.

When I make a GET request to a controller method that doesn't have a constructor, I get a 200 response. For example,

**Controller without constructor**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ApiController : Controller
{
    protected static BusinessLogic BusinessLogic;

[HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
```

But when I instantiate the constructor, I get a 500 response. What am I missing?

**Controller**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ApiController : Controller
{
    protected static BusinessLogic BusinessLogic;
    public ApiController(BusinessLogic businessLogic)
    {
        BusinessLogic = businessLogic;
    }

[HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
```

**Business Logic**

```
public class BusinessLogic
{
    private readonly Encryption _encryption;
    private readonly string UserID;
    private readonly string Password;

    public BusinessLogic(string Key, string Url, string UserId, string Password)
    {
        _encryption = new Encryption(Key);
        _UserID = UserId;
        _Password = Password;
    }
```

Comment: "500 response" is just the HTTP response code. What is the exception that is raised?

Comment: The constructor is not the problem, the problem is that the constructor has a parameter that has to be fulfilled by something. Are you looking for [Dependency Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection)?

Comment: (Side note) - **Don't use a static field for BusinessLogic**. You are writing code that has to be thread safe, adding a static field that you then assign in an instance constructor and has fields of it's own that appear to be context sensitive will cause race conditions (bugs) as soon as you have more than 1 user accessing the application at a time.

Comment: @Igor Can you also please mention the reason for that

Comment: Is it not already there in my comment? What do you not understand about that?

Comment: If you don't want to use IOC you'll have to instantiate BusinessLogic in the controller constructor

Comment: @Noel How to do that ?

Comment: Honestly there are a lot of mistakes in the code shown and not enough code to understand what it is you want to do. Also your follow up questions are very broad. I recommend you find a tutorial on asp.net web api, there are *many* out there. Follow one of those first (with sample code) and then try yours again to see if it makes more sense.

Comment: Alright. Thank you @Igor

Comment: @JoshMuroe: new BusinessLogic("myKey", "myUrl", "myUserId", "myPassword"). I'm not sure where you'll get the values (Request.Headers?) or how they will be used from BusinessLogic.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must inject your service into the controller

Look at this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection) of Microsoft for the detail about dependency injection

In summary, you must create a interface `IBusinessLogic`, register it with an implementation `BusinessLogic` and inject the interface to the controller by the constructor.

```
container.RegisterType<IBusinessLogic, BusinessLogic>();
```

Comment: I dont want to use DI or IoC. Is there an easier way of doing it

Comment: `I don't want to use DI or IoC. Is there an easier way of doing it` <= Why @JoshMuroe ?

Comment: @Igor I am new to it and don't understand the concept yet.

Answer (score 0):

The static business object is a nonstandard way of doing what you want, but is valid, but would need a mutex in the method to be threadsafe. Most people would instantiate the business object every thread through Dependency Injection in the constructor, but the 500 error is probably because there is no Dependency Injection framework to instantiate and inject the business object.see Microsoft unity or castleWindsor. 
The 200 is 
Success, but I'm not sure how as you're inheriting from Controller, a MVC class, not Apicontroller which should be used for webapi methods.